# mysql max(date) not working

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have this query that is supposed to return some information like price, open, close, etc.. for the LATEST entry.

```
SELECT * FROM History WHERE symbol = $symbol Having max(`date`);
```

But for whatever reason its not returning the correct information. It for some reason believes that the max date is 2013-02-14, but if i look at all the data the most recent is actually 2013-02-27.
in this particular case

```
$symbol = "AGNC"
```

Does the max function not work on date?

Comment: What is the structure of History table? what is the date column name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to have something like this. I'm not fan of doing this using `ORDER BY` clause because there are some possibilities (*although much little*) that records may have the same latest `date` entry.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    History
WHERE   symbol = $symbol AND
        date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM History)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d65b8/1)

Comment: Well that worked.. But i dont get it. Why/How is that different?

Comment: @brandenwagner what do you mean by *Why/How is that different?*?

Comment: Why does that show the right date but my original query does not?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be not using `MAX` at all; if what you want to do is only fetching the latest entry in the table, you could try:

`SELECT * FROM History WHERE symbol = $symbol ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;`

This works perfectly as long as your `date` field is actually declared as a date-related MySQL field type, like `date`, `datetime`, etc.

As JW pointed out in his answer, you may want to add more fields in your `ORDER BY` statement to disambiguate records that have the exact same date.

Also, you may want to put $symbol in quotes if that's a string field (`char`, `varchar`, etc):

`SELECT * FROM History WHERE symbol = '$symbol' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;`

Cheers!

Comment: and this will not handle duplicates right? example, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d65b8/2

Comment: The LIMIT 1 part will ensure only one record is returned if that's what you mean; if several rows have the same date, it will pick one of them and return it. Which one it picks would depend on additional ORDER BY fields (if nothing else is specified, the returned record can't be guaranteed to be the one you're looking for. Still, I reckon it's a more efficient approach since it doesn't rely on running a subquery and a MySQL function...

Comment: Clarifying my latest comment - the author of the question stated he wanted only the latest entry (not entries). Assuming that he only wants one record, my statement does the trick with more efficiency as it doesn't require a subquery. However, if the author does need -all- entries published on the maximum date, then your statement is indeed the best option. Cheers JW!

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM History h
WHERE symbol = $symbol and
      `date` = (select max(`date`) from History where symbol = $symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use alias table name:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    History
WHERE   symbol = $symbol AND
date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM History);
```